# how to choose status within all name in noSQL (MongoDB)

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I have this JSON type document

```
{
    "user": {
        "honza": {
            "email": "haha",
            "telephone": "5454",
            "status": "online"
        },
        "sara": {
            "email": "sdfsdf",
            "telephone": "656",
            "status": "online"
        },
        "michal": {
            "email": "sdfdsffdsfds",
            "telephone": "45454",
            "status": "offline"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find names, which have online status. I'm a begginner and couldn't find any example.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) ?

Comment: Is this the database structure or is this one document?

Comment: @SimonKirsten it is one document

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using **elemMatch** in your query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/